# Print all terms of loss function tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, logging, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm defining a custom loss function. For eg, let's take the `loss function = L1 loss + L2 loss.`
When I do `model.fit_generator()`, the overall loss function is printed after every batch. But I want to see the individual values of `L1 loss` and `L2 loss`. How can I do this?
I want to know the value of individual terms to know their relative scales.

1. `tf.print(l1_loss, output_stream=sys.stdout)` is throwing an exception saying `tensorflow.python.eager.core._FallbackException: This function does not handle the case of the path where all inputs are not already EagerTensors.`.
2. Even `tf.print('---')` just prints `---` at the beginning and not for every batch.
3. `tf.keras.backend.print_tensor(l1_loss)` is not printing anything

Comment: have you tried `sess.run(l1_loss)` and `sess.run(l2_loss)`, with necessary `feed_dict`s?

Comment: I'm using tensorflow 2.0. I'm training model using `model.fit_generator()`. There is no place to do `sess.run()` here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing your code, I can only guess that you didn't decorate your custom loss function with the `@tf.function` decorator.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function  # <-- Be sure to use this decorator.
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.math.abs(y_pred - y_true))
  tf.print(loss)  # <-- Use tf.print(), instead of print(). You can print not just 'loss', but any TF tensor in this function using this approach.
  return loss

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=[8]))
model.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer="sgd")

x_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([np.ones(8)] * 100)
y_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([np.ones(1)] * 100)
data = tf.data.Dataset.zip((x_data, y_data)).batch(2)

model.fit_generator(data, steps_per_epoch=10, epochs=2)
```

The output looks like the following, which tells you the batch-by-batch loss values.

```
Epoch 1/2
0.415590227  1/10 [==>...........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.41560.325590253
0.235590339
0.145590425
0.0555904508
0.034409523
0.0555904508
0.034409523
0.0555904508
0.034409523 10/10 [==============================] - 0s 11ms/step - loss: 0.1392 Epoch 2/2
0.0555904508  1/10 [==>...........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.05560.034409523
0.0555904508
0.034409523
0.0555904508
0.034409523
0.0555904508
0.034409523
0.0555904508
0.034409523 10/10 [==============================] - 0s 498us/step - loss: 0.0450
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know about the `tf.function` decorator. That is all I was missing. Are there any caveats with using that decorator, that I should be aware of before using it? In the docs, I read something like `eager execution` with this decorator.

Comment: Is it possible to write a callback method as a `tf.function`. I am looking for ways to print each loss terms of my loss function `on_epoch_end`. Any help appreciated!

Comment: @satyanarayanrao, I'm sure its easily possible although I don't know how.  I suggest you open up your own new question as what you're asking is fairly different than the OP, and you may get more responses.